# Simple event system, can't remove listeners from list

Tags: c#

I made a simple event system by following a tutorial, the registration of listeners and firing events works well, but I can't remove any listener from it.

```
    delegate void EventListener(EventInfoBase eventInfo);
    Dictionary<System.Type, List<EventListener>> eventListeners;

    public void RegisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener) where T : EventInfoBase
    {
        System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

        if (eventListeners == null)
        {
            eventListeners = new Dictionary<System.Type, List<EventListener>>();
        }

        if (!eventListeners.ContainsKey(eventType) || eventListeners[eventType] == null)
        {
            eventListeners[eventType] = new List<EventListener>();
        }

        EventListener wrapper = (ei) => { listener((T)ei); };

        eventListeners[eventType].Add(wrapper);

    }

    public void UnregisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener) where T : EventInfoBase
    {
        System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

        if (eventListeners == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!eventListeners.ContainsKey(eventType) || eventListeners[eventType] == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        EventListener wrapper = (ei) => { listener((T)ei); };

        EventListener toRemove = eventListeners[eventType].Find(x => x.Equals(wrapper));
        //EventListener toRemove = eventListeners[eventType].Find(x => x.Target == wrapper.Target && x.Method == wrapper.Method);

        if (toRemove != null)
        {
            eventListeners[eventType].Remove(toRemove); // Never gets called
        }

    }
```

This is how it's called (it's a singleton):

```
EventsSystem.Instance.RegisterListener<EventInfoWin>(OnWin);
EventsSystem.Instance.UnregisterListener<EventInfoWin>(OnWin);
```

So I expected the listener to be removed from appropriate list, but it stays there. The UnregisterListener method does nothing. Any way to fix it quickly without rewriting everything?

Comment: Is `OnWin` the same instance in both cases?

Comment: Basically, your wrappers aren't equal to each other. There are lots of ways to change this, but it's hard to know the best one to use without knowing how the event listeners are used. I'd almost certainly store the actions *directly*, without any wrappers. Your dictionary would need to become "somewhat untyped" in that it would be a `Dictionary<Type, object>`, with each value being a `List<T>` for the key type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in `RegisterListener<T>` you create an anonymous wrapper method of type `EventListener` and in `UnregisterListener<T>` you create *another* wrapper method. These wrappers will never match.

What you can do is to store the original listener along with the wrapper. That will allow you to match with the original listener, but execute the wrapper (to execute the original listener you would need reflection - hence the wrapper). If you switch from a dictionary to a list of tuples, you can do this in a straightforward way:

```
delegate void EventListener(object eventInfo);
List<(System.Type Type, Delegate Listener, EventListener Wrapper)> eventListeners;

public void RegisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener)
{
    System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

    if (eventListeners == null)
    {
        eventListeners = new List<(System.Type, Delegate, EventListener)>();
    }

    if (!eventListeners.Any(entry => entry.Type.Equals(eventType) &&
        entry.Listener.Equals(listener))) {

        eventListeners.Add((eventType, listener, ei => listener((T)ei)));
    }
}

public void UnregisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener)
{
    System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

    if (eventListeners == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var toRemove = eventListeners.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Type.Equals(eventType) &&
        entry.Listener.Equals(listener));

    eventListeners.Remove(toRemove);
}
```

You can try it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmVhA3).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the wrapper delegate as you do. the reason is, that this is creating another "object" on adding, which will not be be recognizable later when you want to remove it.
As Jon Skeet wrote, you can just save the action directly, but as an **object**. I've tested it, and I did not find a way to have an list with *Action of EventInfoBase* putting in an *Action of EventInfoWin*.

So that is what it could look like:

EDIT: I've created a wrapper again, but with the original action as a token to find it again.

```
    delegate void EventListener(EventInfoBase eventInfo);

    private class EventWrapper
    {
        public EventListener Action { get; set; }
        public object Token { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<System.Type, List<EventWrapper>> eventListeners = new Dictionary<System.Type, List<EventWrapper>>();


    public void RegisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener) where T : EventInfoBase
    {
        System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

        if (!eventListeners.ContainsKey(eventType) || eventListeners[eventType] == null)
        {
            eventListeners[eventType] = new List<EventWrapper>();
        }

        EventListener action = (ei) => { listener((T)ei); };
        var wrapper = new EventWrapper() { Action = action, Token = listener };

        eventListeners[eventType].Add(wrapper);

    }

    public void UnregisterListener<T>(System.Action<T> listener) where T : EventInfoBase
    {
        System.Type eventType = typeof(T);

        if (!eventListeners.ContainsKey(eventType) || eventListeners[eventType] == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var toRemove = eventListeners[eventType].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Token.Equals(listener));

        if (toRemove != null)
        {
            eventListeners[eventType].Remove(toRemove);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fire the listeners? It seems I can't cast the objects that are in the list to Action<EventInfoBase>

Comment: @BeginnerSirius: I've update the code. I re-entered the concept of a wrapper. But there is now also the original Action to find it again later.